# React Native error after installing third party library

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using `react-native init` for native development, I run `react-native run-ios` and it starts the simulator just fine. But when I try to install a third party library I get an error, in this case I am trying to use React Native Elements.

This is the error:
[image]

What's worse, even if I comment out the code from the third party library and use regular native code, I get the same error (this happens only after installing the third party library)

[image]

I followed thi steps as per documentation: `npm i react-native-elements --save`

I also made sure to run this command again `npm install -g react-native-cli`and then ran `react-native link`

I have tried:

```
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: rm -rf node_modules && npm install
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-* or npm start -- --reset-cache
  4. Remove haste cache: rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-
```

I love working with React but I never imagined that developing native apps with React Native would be this painful... Is there anything I can do to fix this? Or should just use Expo instead?

Answer (score 0):

This error normally comes when your device not been able to load bundle from react-native packager please make sure your are loading your JS bundle from react-native packager.
In my opinion you are not loading your JS bundle.
Bundler will start automatically when you run your app in Xcode and it app will load JS bundle sometimes you just need to reload the application with cmd+R.
If you are loading your JS bundle and after load of bundle this error occurs this is a problem in your app registry where you registering your app in index.js file.

Answer (score 0):

That could happen due to react native link break or could be from the react native cache.
Try the following
- watchman watch-del-all
- react-native start --reset-cache
- rm -rf node_modules && npm install

If that does not work,
- react-native upgrade (It auto fixes any broken links, you can just revert your commit if you don't want to keep it, with `git checkout .`) That should help